# Proving $f(x)$ is strictly increasing if $f'''(x) \gt 0$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:**
>
> Let f: X $\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and suppose it is differentiable and that $f'(x_0)= f''(x_0) = 0,$ and $f'''(x_0)\gt0$, Prove that $f$ is strictly increasing at $x_0$.

**My attempt**

I feel this has something to do with L'hopitals rule. So I began by defining $$g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^3}$$

By L'hopitals rule $$g'(x_0) = \frac{f'''(x_0)}{6} \gt 0$$
Therefore $g(x)$ is strictly increasing at $x_0$.

This must imply that $f(x)$ is also strictly increasing no?

Is any of this correct? Thank you

Comment: That is not part of the question given unfortunately

Comment: L'Hopital's rule does not tell you that that is the derivative of $g$ at $x_0$. Instead the quotient rule tells you it's $(f'(x_0)x_0^3-3f(x_0)x_0^2)/(x_0^6)=-3f(x_0)/x_0^4$, which could be positive, negative, or 0.

Comment: what does "strictly increasing at $x_0$" mean?

Comment: Have you tried taking a taylor expansion?

Comment: I think "is differentiable" right before giving the derivatives was meant "we can define the following derivatives", and so it's ok.

Comment: @zhw.: I suppose OP means the usual definition of strictly increasing at a point (this is what I have used in my answer, but OP should confirm). If $f$ is strictly increasing at $a$ then it means that there is a neighborhood $I$ of $a$ such that $x \in I, x < a$ implies $f(x) < f(a)$ and $x \in I, x > a$ implies $f(x) > f(a)$.

Comment: Thanks, the definition was unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea. Put $\;g(x):=f'(x)\;$ , then we're given

$$\begin{cases}f''(x_0)=g'(x_0)=0\\{}\\f'''(x_0)=g''(x_0)>0\end{cases}\;\;\implies (x_0,g(x_0))\;\;\text{is a local minimum of}\;\;f'(x)=g(x)$$

Since $\;f'(x_0)=g(x_0)=0\;$ , this means there's a neighborhood $\;I_\epsilon:=(x_0-\epsilon,\,x_0+\epsilon)\;$ for which $\;f'(x)=g(x)\ge0\;\;\forall\,x\in I_\epsilon\;$ , and this means $\;f(x)\;$ monotonic non-decreasing in $\;I_\epsilon\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

I am replacing $x_{0}$ by $a$ to save some typing effort. Now $f'''(a) > 0$ implies that $f''$ is *strictly increasing at $a$*. This means that there is a neighborhood $I$ of $a$ such that if $x \in I, x < a$ then $f''(x) < f''(a) = 0$ and if $x \in I, x > a$ then $f''(x) > f''(a) = 0$.

Next if $x \in I$ then $$f'(x) = f'(x) - f'(a) = (x - a)f''(c)$$ for some $c$ between $a$ and $x$ and by what we have established in the previous paragraph it follows that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$ except $x = a$. And therefore $f$ is strictly increasing in interval $I$. *This is far more stronger than saying that $f$ is strictly increasing at $a$.*

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I have never said that $f'(a) > 0$ leads to an interval $I$ containing $a$ in which $f$ is increasing. I have said that $f'(a) > 0$ implies that $f$ is strictly increasing at $a$ and this has a well defined meaning which I have given in my answer. Please read my first paragraph again.

Comment: You're right, the answer seems fine then. +1

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Thanks man!